# Protecting data sent using web services

Tags: angularjs, web-services

I am very new at this so this might seem like a noob question.

I am making an application that makes heavy use of AngularJS. In my front end pages, I am populating dropdowns, user lists, and so on.

When I am sending data from my web services, I am sending both the itemId and the itemName. The itemName is used to populate my front end, and the itemId will be used if the user interacts with that particular item.

The problem is that, the user can open the network log of the browser, or use a tool like Fiddler and see all the itemIds. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if the user fiddles with data, they should expect the application to behave badly. That being said, as long as your security is tight on the back-end, and the user cannot make changes to anything they shouldn't be able to, you'll be fine.

Assume all data from the client application is bad/faulty/attempting to exploit your service, that's the only way to maintain security.

There's no way to maintain any sort of "secure" data in a JS application, and so its input cannot be trusted implicitly.

Comment: I will be handling the input validation anyway at the back end ... but my problem is that they are knowing what are the primary keys of all my records

Comment: I guess I don't see why that's an issue. If it truly is, then you need to not expose the primary key to the client at any point. That said, you'll still need the client to be able to uniquely identify the resources/entities so whatever faux-primary key you invent will be functionally identical.

Comment: consider a list of users. using fiddler you know each user's primary key field .... i dont know whether this is an issue ..since i will be validating input anyway ... is this an issue?

Comment: If your primary keys are just arbitrary values, it's fine. If your pk's are something sensitive like a Social Security #, then you need to proxy those with some arbitrary auto-increment field. Making PK values known is not inherently a risk as long as the application treats user input with the level of trust it deserves: zero.